# Как мне редактировать стили div отдельно?

Tags: html, css

Например:у меня 2 div я хочу , чтоб содерижимый текст первого был синий, а содержимый текст второго был красный, но когда я пишу в css стиль div, то стиль применяется к обеим содержимым. Я знаю, что можно использовать Section , но хотелось бы узнать можно ли по другому используя в обеих случаях div

```
   div {
        padding-top: 100px;
        padding-left: 100px;
       }
   div {
        padding-top: 150px;
        padding-left: 200px;
       }
```

Comment: Про id и class вы пока не знаете, правильно?

Comment: @fixer Возможно у него стоит задача разобраться с разметкой, которую нельзя менять, но он не знает как. Преподаватель например задал домашнюю работу.

Answer (score 0):

> можно ли по другому используя в обеих случаях div

Например можно таким способом - указав порядковый номер элемента. https://hcdev.ru/css/nth-child/#_1

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: blue;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div></div>
```